# Android messenger with whatsapp-like interface, but using e-mail

Tags: android, chat

I'm looking for an android messaging app that has an interface similar to whatsapp or telegram (contacts list, recent chats list, group chats), but uses email to transfer messages.

Conversations should also be displayed chat-style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delta Chat https://getdelta.org/ does exactly what I asked here; uses IMAP+SMTP.